# How to parse an unusual array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I am using the '[cordova-brother-label-printer](https://github.com/gordol/cordova-brother-label-printer)' cordova plugin to get a list of printers. The `findNetworkPrinters` function returns the data like so:

```
[{nodeName=PrinterName123456, serNo=Serial12345, ipAddress=192.168.1.134, macAddress=MA:CA:DD:RE:SS}]
```

This isn't a standard JSON-encoded string so I cannot parse it using JSON.parse. Is there another way to convert this into JSON?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are no built-in methods to parse that format … whatever that format is. Write your own parser or find a third party library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.replace()` with RegExp to reformat the string to the JSON format and parse it using `JSON.parse()`:

```js
const str = '[{nodeName=PrinterName123456, serNo=Serial12345, ipAddress=192.168.1.134, macAddress=MA:CA:DD:RE:SS}]';

const json = str
  .replace(/([^\[\]{}=\s,]+)/g, '"$1"')
  .replace(/=/g, ':');

console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

Comment: @DanielHutton this will fail in there are spaces or quotes in the printer name. These are not treated specially in the format in your question, so it's not okay to assume they can't appear. This is a horrible answer. Write your own parser.

Comment: @user234461 - this is a specific answer tailored to this case, and should be updated according to the data. It doesn't handle anything else by design.

Comment: @OriDrori Here's another "specific answer tailored to this case": `str.replace(/=Serial12435/, '="Serial12345"')`. Can you see the problem? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

- `{` with `{"`
- `}` with `"}`
- `,\s*` with `","`
- `=` with `":"`

In this order to create a valid JSON string and then parse.

```js
var input = "[{nodeName=PrinterName123456, serNo=Serial12345, ipAddress=192.168.1.134, macAddress=MA:CA:DD:RE:SS}]";
var output = JSON.parse(
   input.replace(/{/g,'{"')
        .replace(/}/g, '"}')
        .replace(/,\s*/g, '","')
        .replace(/=/g, '":"')
   );

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I will accept Ori's as he answered first but I appreciate the help.

Comment: @DanielHutton Sure, glad that answer could help.

Answer (score 1):

With javascript's `replace` function, you should be able to convert this to valid JSON.

Try this:

```
var inputString = '[{nodeName=PrinterName123456, serNo=Serial12345, ipAddress=192.168.1.134, macAddress=MA:CA:DD:RE:SS}]';
var json = JSON.parse(inputString.replace(/([^={]*)=([^,}]*)(,\s?)?/g, '"$1": "$2"$3'));
```

The regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/AMCNlh/1